# How would you create a hole in this face?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I would want the hole to go through the other side. And additional question: How would you connect the verts on that face if I wouldn't want to put a hole on it? And lastly what modeling process would you recommend: would you create a highly dense object just for the tiny bevels on the edges?

Comment: Hello :). Are you after quad based topology? Do you want to use Subdivision Surface modifier, or Bevel modifier? And what have *you* tried so far? :)

Comment: @Jachym Michal Hi, Thanks for commenting! What do you recommend if I want the model for various works like for a game, for an HD rendered image, or just to be used as a prop for reference for a 2d artwork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford the polygons generated by subdivision-surface modelling, there are a lot of advantages in keeping the initial poly-count as low as possible, and modelling the hole in the flat...

[image]

... working with geometry something like the above.

1. Inset region
2. Slide some edges about to make a vaguely circular region of the inset
3. Shipped add-on, *Loop Tools > Circle*
4. Inset again, and delete the hole
5. Cut in half, maybe make a cut or two to get rid of the poles created by the insets, and slide verts for better flow.

Now you're all set up to modify on the stack:

[image]

- *Mirror* in X and Y
- *Solidify* outwards
- *Bevel* by angle, to hold the..
- ..*Subdivision Surface*.

The result is a handle with only 25-odd faces to look after, making it easy to adjust. You can change the size of the holes, the depth and curvature of the handle, and of its rounded ends.. all sorts, with simple selections and moves.

Personally, I would even model this way for low-poly; applying the modifiers, and knocking out loops where that does not damage the curvatures too much.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight! Can ask multiple questions?: How would you make the final model? I know about the subdivision workflow with its easy editing. Now what is the best polycount and topology would you recommend, because you can model this in any way, but the final model is all that matters anyway. How many subdivisions, and number of bevels would you recommend for the high poly model, if i was gonna bake the details to the final low poly one. And additionally how would you model this if you were gonna use it just for a rendered image. Thank You for the help!

Comment: @Ypil Assuming no e.g. game constraints, I would make the final model exactly as shown. 2 Levels of subdiv usually 'disappears' segmentation of curves, at this kind of density. Even for High poly,  minimum loops to capture the curvature, hold straight segments. while being lazy (not being _too_ fanatical about removing every possible loop) 3. The bevels here are holding loops for the subdiv, so 2 segments, profile 1.. reduce profile to soften  the appearance. For baking? If you want to sculpt detail into the surface, as high as you like. But for something like this, boilerplate normal maps?

Comment: Oh well thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a boolean modifier with a cylinder as shown in the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!